# Minimax algorithm and checking every option / keeping track of best move in C

Tags: c, algorithm

I try to make a tic tac toe game using minimax algorithm, but I have a hard time with recursion and keeping track of best move. 
Now, my function returns a score when there is a winner, and then deletes that move from a board. My question is, how to prevent it to search the same child node again?

```
int minimax(Board *board, int depth, char player, Position lastPosition)
{
    Position avMoves;
    int score = -2;

    if (didTheGameEnd(*board, (player == 'X') ? 'O' : 'X', lastPosition) == 1) {
        return (depth % 2 != 0) ? -10 : 10;
    } else if (didTheGameEnd(*board, (player == 'X') ? 'O' : 'X', lastPosition) == -1) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (board->numberOfBlanks != 0) {
        avMoves = getAvaliableMoves(*board);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < board->numberOfBlanks; i++) {
        int newScore;
        placeMark(board, player, avMoves);
        newScore = minimax(board, depth+1, changePlayer(player), avMoves);
        if (depth % 2 != 0) {
            if (newScore > score) {
                score = newScore;
            }
        } else {
            if (newScore < score) {
                score = newScore;
            }
        }
        board->boardArr[avMoves.y][avMoves.x] = '-';
        board->numberOfBlanks++;
        board->numberOfOccupied--;
    }
    return score;
}
```

How to return the best move ?
**EDIT** I forgot to add, that I try to make this on N size board

Answer (score 2):

it may be helpful to look at the source code for Tom Kerrigan's "simple chess program" below

basically the following code is part of the alpha-beta (minmax) function.  It generates the moves and loops over the moves in the for loop checking if there are any legal moves to be made (this is necessary as chess uses pseudo-legal move generators) part of the key to returning the best variation is use of a "triangular array" that collects the best variation in pv[0][0..pv_length[0]]. pv_length keeps track of the length of the best variation at various depth of the gametree. Its a tedious indexing scheme but gets the job done.

```
gen();
    if (follow_pv)  /* are we following the PV? */
        sort_pv();
    f = FALSE;

    /* loop through the moves */
    for (i = first_move[ply]; i < first_move[ply + 1]; ++i) {
        sort(i);
        if (!makemove(gen_dat[i].m.b))
            continue;
        f = TRUE;
        x = -search(-beta, -alpha, depth - 1);
        takeback();
        if (x > alpha) {

            /* this move caused a cutoff, so increase the history
               value so it gets ordered high next time we can
               search it */
            history[(int)gen_dat[i].m.b.from][(int)gen_dat[i].m.b.to] += depth;
            if (x >= beta)
                return beta;
            alpha = x;

            /* update the PV */
            pv[ply][ply] = gen_dat[i].m;
            for (j = ply + 1; j < pv_length[ply + 1]; ++j)
                pv[ply][j] = pv[ply + 1][j];
            pv_length[ply] = pv_length[ply + 1];
        }
    }

    /* no legal moves? then we're in checkmate or stalemate */
    if (!f) {
        if (c)
            return -10000 + ply;
        else
            return 0;
    }

    /* fifty move draw rule */
    if (fifty >= 100)
        return 0;
    return alpha;
}
```

Comment: I'm struggling with getting possible moves, as it is N board size I don't know how many there are moves I try to do this by a dynamically allocated array, but I don't exactly know where I should place this allocation / freeing.

Answer (score 2):

**How to return the best move?**

You check each possible move and return the one with the best score. Of course as soon as you found a winning move you can return it immediately.

What makes it difficult is the design of your function. You would have to make the move and then call the function with the move that was made, revert it and test the next one. If you redesign your function to take `nextPosition` instead of `lastPosition` as parameter and then execute that move inside the function things will be a little easier.

**How to prevent the same positions to be searched again?**

Use a lookup table. A position can easily be represented by 18 bits, a single integer, e.g. by using the first 9 bits to say where the `X` pieces are and the next 9 bits where the `O` pieces are. It would be possible with fewer bits but then you need complicated en- and decoding.

```
X X -
- O -   =   110 000 000  000 010 001   =   196625
- - O
```

I also suggest to have a look at alpha-beta pruning, with good move ordering (try the promising ones first) you can cut off whole branches and save a lot of time. For tic tac toe it doesn't matter, but as soon as it gets a little more complex it helps a lot.

Comment: lastPosition is used in function which is checking if player win so that this function doesn't need to search whole board but the row/col where a mark was placed.

Comment: You design the function in such a way that it answers the question: what score will i get if i would play this move? (instead of: what score does the board have now?). So you would only need to find all possible moves and call the function with it to find the best one, execution of move and revert is done in the function.